# AS seems to not work in influxDB continuous queries

Tags: influxdb, continuous

The query was 
`CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_one ON experiments BEGIN SELECT sum(value) AS value, sum(count) AS count INTO business_experiments.autogen.rollup FROM business_experiments.autogen.experiment GROUP BY time(1m), * END` 
but the value and count ended up as sum and sum_1, thusly 
`select * from rollup limit 1
time                 server count dId dsName ex ipVersion pId  pName     region sum                sum_1 value
----                 -------- ----- ----- ------- ---- --------- -----  -------     ------ ---                ----- -----
2018-07-30T23:37:00Z 1              10    Absurd  0    4         176280 Odball NA     1.7999999999999998 3`

sum and sum1 had the value and count, value were empty.
Anyone know if the syntax changed?

Comment: Which database platform is this for, maybe InfluxDB? If so, I'm not familiar with the syntax, but tagging your question with that platform (and maybe referencing it in the question) might attract someone more familiar with that tool.

Comment: Thanks, corrected